# Deklination des Wortes "jed-"

Tags: grammar, adjective, declension

Wie ist die Deklination des Wortes *jed-*?

**1. Frage:**
Gibt es das Wort *jede* im Plural oder nicht? *(Bitte kleines Beispiel oder einen Link geben.)*

In English das Wort jede bedeutet: *every, each, any;*

und ich kann nicht verstehen, wie (mit dieser Bedeutung) dieses Wort im Singular genutzt werden kann.

Ist das unten richtig *(falls es einen Plural von* jen- *gibt)*?

```
PLURAL(?)   
Nominativ: jede   guten Hunde
Akkusativ: jede   guten Hunde
Dativ    : jeden  guten Hunden
Genitiv  : jeder  guten Hunde
```

**2. Frage:**
Wie ist die Deklination von *jed-* im Singular? *(Bitte bestätigen oder einen Link geben.)*

Ist das Folgende richtig im Maskulinum?

```
SINGULAR    
Nominativ: jeder  gute  Mann
Akkusativ: jeden  guten Mann
Dativ    : jedem  guten Mann
Genitiv  : jedes  guten Mannes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Plural, den Du suchst, ist "alle": "alle guten Hunde" und so weiter. Der Rest ist richtig.

Comment: So es gibt KEINE plural Form für das Wort jed-? Sind Sie sicher?

Comment: Ja. http://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/jeder

Comment: Danke Schon i am not very well versed with online learning and i am trying very hard to learn German!

Comment: Herr Schultz i am trying on this page which i do not doubt is very useful for me to find how you can search for a word. It does not seem to have a search box like Google

Comment: is there a way to use this machine and check out if this is right: jeder gute Mann (with an adjectiv)?